# How to identify which button was pressed in javascript?

Tags: javascript, button

How to identify which button was pressed in javascript

in have 4 buttons that present items and text box

when i press a buttons, the number in the text box add to sum

Comment: `this` usually refers to the clicked button, but without seeing your code I can't say more.

Comment: Ideally you should always provide a Fiddle demo for it but I have made one for you as it is so simple, http://jsfiddle.net/6WQ5c/

Comment: Is it a bit like this [javascript calculator](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut18.shtml)?

Answer (score 1):

We would really like to help you but you should provide some more information how you would like to realize that and what your actual code looks like.

Did you say that you are trying to realize a calculator? There are many ways how to identify the button which was triggered, e.g. pressed. In the example you provided above ([Calculator](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/cut18.shtml)) a javascript function is called if the user clicks on a specific button. To achieve that, the function call is made within the onClick event:

```
<INPUT type="button" name="one" value="1" OnClick="btnPressed(1)">
```

The called function could look like this:

```
function btnPressed(value){
    var obj = document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox')
    obj.value = parseInt(obj.value) + value
}
```

If you would like to identify which button was clicked, you can do it with the numbers stored in the 'value' argument. Or on the other hand you could change the trigger to:

```
<INPUT type="button" name="one" value="1" OnClick="btnPressed(1, this)">
```

and the JS function to:

```
function btnPressed(value, sender){
    ...
}
```

If you are willing to use the 'this' reference like illustrated above, then you can also do a step further and change the whole thing to something like this:

```
<INPUT type="button" name="one" value="1" OnClick="btnPressed(this)">

function btnPressed(sender){
    var obj = document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox')
    obj.value = parseInt(obj.value) + parseInt(sender.value)
}
```

You can also do it directly in the onClick of the INPUT:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="1" OnClick="document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox').value) + 1">
```

or:

```
<INPUT type="button" value="1" OnClick="document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('ID_of_textbox').value) + parseInt(this.value)">
```